# Mysql merge 2 values in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this below. name table *doc* from database *app*

```
mysql> use app;
mysql> select id,name,mix from doc;
+-----+---------+-----------+
| id  | name    | mix       |
+-----+---------+-----------+
| 12  | Apple   |           |
| 15  | Mango   |           |
| 26  | Banana  |           |
| 41  | Coconut |           |
| 87  | Avocado |           |
| 112 | Cherry  |           |
| 136 | Grape   |           |
| 204 | Lemon   |           |
+-----+---------+-----------+
```

i want to merge 2 values from column *id* and *name* in table *doc* and the result is like this in column *mix*.

```
mysql> select id,name,mix from doc;
+-----+---------+-----------+
| id  | name    | mix       |
+-----+---------+-----------+
| 12  | Apple   | Apple12   |
| 15  | Mango   | Mango15   |
| 26  | Banana  | Banana26  |
| 41  | Coconut | Coconut41 |
| 87  | Avocado | Avocado87 |
| 112 | Cherry  | Cherry112 |
| 136 | Grape   | Grape136  |
| 204 | Lemon   | Lemon204  |
+-----+---------+-----------+
```

is this possible to get result like that. i need code in **php-mysql**.

> in this point i need insert new values from clumn id,name to clumn mix

anyone can help me. i'm still beginner in **php-mysql**.
Thanks a lot for someone who can help.

Comment: You'll need to write the PHP to run the MySQL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the mix column, use this:

```
update doc set mix = concat(name,id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values using MySQL in your **SELECT** statement like so:

```
SELECT id,name,CONCAT(name,id) AS mix FROM doc
```

If you want to create a new column and fill it with data from the other columns, you would use:

```
ALTER TABLE doc ADD COLUMN mix VARCHAR(32);
UPDATE doc SET mix = CONCAT(name,id);
```

That said, usually the data would be combined on the select to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id name CONCAT(id, name) as mix FROM doc;
```

Edit: if you want to update column then you need update query

```
update doc set mix = concat(name,id);
```

Comment: thank you for your fast feedback. but how to insert new values in column mix above. in this point i need insert new values from clumn id,name to clumn mix.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.MySQL `CONCAT` function is used to concatenate two strings to form a single string.

```
SELECT id,name,CONCAT(name,id) as mix FROM doc;
```

**Output**:

```
    +-----+---------+-----------+
    | id  | name    | mix       |
    +-----+---------+-----------+
    | 12  | Apple   | Apple12   |
    | 15  | Mango   | Mango15   |
    | 26  | Banana  | Banana26  |
    | 41  | Coconut | Coconut41 |
    | 87  | Avocado | Avocado87 |
    | 112 | Cherry  | Cherry112 |
    | 136 | Grape   | Grape136  |
    | 204 | Lemon   | Lemon204  |
    +-----+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `doc` table using `CONCAT()`:

```
UPDATE doc
SET mix = CONCAT(id,name)
```

Comment: Hii Tim Biegeleisen, thanks a lot. this fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pranji, You can use CONCAT command to concatenate two different values in SQL.
Here I'm using default tables in SQL developer to give a simple example to you.
e.g.

```
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME FROM EMP;
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME, CONCAT(EMPNO,ENAME) FROM EMP;
```